# Is there any existing syntax checker for GNU R

Tags: r, syntax

Is there any existing tool to perform the same function as 'jslint' or 'php -l'?

For a large scale project, how can we ensure source code without any typo error before any unit test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is the `codetools` package (especially the `checkUsage` function) and the `lint` function in the `svTools` package.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes I got the lintr checker from here to work:**

https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/lintr.html

https://github.com/jimhester/lintr

**Installation for Vim:**

Put the file syntastic/lintr.vim under the syntastic/syntax_checkers/r directory. If you are using pathogen this directory is ~/.vim/bundles/syntastic/syntax_checkers/r.

Then add the following lines to your .vimrc.

```
let g:syntastic_enable_r_lintr_checker = 1
let g:syntastic_r_checkers = ['lintr']
```

Start vim and it should work, here is mine:

[image]